# Automatically calculate value on input using onkeyup

Tags: javascript

I have some code that calculates the amount of frames based on some users input. I can get this to work when I input the data manually into the function, but I would like this to be calculated automatically via "onkeyup" on the input field, so I changed the code a little to do that, but it doesn't work. It throws the exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at processChunk (0eaace3b-4b4c-4c76-93c5-8e8921ae247c:309)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (0eaace3b-4b4c-4c76-93c5-8e8921ae247c:213)
```

Script that has the issue.

```
    var input = document.getElementById("id_desiredFrames").value;  
    var totFrames = 0;

    var chunk = input.split(";")
    chunk.forEach(processChunk);

    document.getElementById("TotalFrames").value = totFrames

    function processChunk(chunk) {
      var stepInfo = chunk.split(",");
      var step = 1;
      if(stepInfo.length > 1)
        step = stepInfo[1];

      var range = stepInfo[0].split("-");
      var frame = Math.round((range[1]- range[0]+ 1) / step);
      totFrames += frame;
    }
```

Script that works but with manual input data:

```
var input = "1-4; 10-20,2"
var totFrames = 0;

var chunk = input.split(";")
chunk.forEach(processChunk);

console.log(totFrames);

function processChunk(chunk) {
  var stepInfo = chunk.split(",");
  var step = 1;
  if(stepInfo.length > 1)
    step = stepInfo[1];

  var range = stepInfo[0].split("-");
  var frame = Math.round((range[1]- range[0]+ 1) / step);
  totFrames += frame;
}
```

`id_desiredFrames` is the input field on my form.
   `TotalFrames` is a hidden field I would like the value to be passed on to, so I can get the value when the user POST

Comment: `var input = document.getElementById("id_desiredFrames").value;` is executed only when the page is loaded. so there are no value on page load. so you can call a function on change of input to get the value.

Comment: `getElementById` returns `null`, not `undefined`

Comment: Also, it doesn't fix your problem, but there is `onchange` eventlistener, which can track the changes in `input` field.

Comment: @Nisheanthan Ohhh, got it. I'm just not sure how to turn it into a function as a whole.

Comment: @LesnieSncheider I'm posting my suggestion as an answer, please have a check on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to call an onchange/onkeyup event to get the value of input field

HTML,

```
<input onkeyup="check()" id="id_desiredFrames"> </input>
```

JS,

```
var totFrames = 0;

function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById("id_desiredFrames").value;  
  var chunk = input.split(";")
  chunk.forEach(processChunk);

  document.getElementById("TotalFrames").value = totFrames
}

function processChunk(chunk) {
  var stepInfo = chunk.split(",");
  var step = 1;
  if(stepInfo.length > 1)
    step = stepInfo[1];

  var range = stepInfo[0].split("-");
  var frame = Math.round((range[1]- range[0]+ 1) / step);
  totFrames += frame;
}
```

hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: When I type into the input field nothing seems to get calculated. The value of `TotalFrames` is just `none`. I tried changing `onchange` to `onkeyup` and that just returns the value `NaN` when inputting the data onto the input field

Comment: Can you share any stackblitz code snippets, so I can figure out exactly where are we getting the problem.

Comment: Here you go. https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-dust-y0yww?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I dont use Angular and stuff like stackblitz use, so I just found something else. Hopes thats ok

Comment: Ah I noticed it assigns the value when you press enter on the input field, but the calculations are wrong now.

Comment: check this [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-visvesvaraya-t90y7)

Comment: It does assign the values but only the first one are correct. If you keep adding values after it has run the function the first time, then it adds up the values instead of calculating just the data from the input only.

Comment: yeah, i see that issue. can you check the same link now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204862/discussion-between-nisheanthan-and-lesnie-sncheider).

Answer (score 0):

It is about `chunk` or `stepInfo[0]`, isn' it? I'd suggest to add a few conditions before function execution - that way it will ~ignore incorrect input at least:

```js
function processChunk(chunk) {
  if (!chunk || chunk.indexOf(',') == -1)
    return;
  var stepInfo = chunk.split(",");
  var step = 1;
  if(stepInfo.length > 1)
    step = stepInfo[1];
  
  if (!stepInfo[0] || stepInfo[0].indexOf('-') == -1)
    return;
  var range = stepInfo[0].split("-");
  var frame = Math.round((range[1]- range[0]+ 1) / step);
  totFrames += frame;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry , the full exception is ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at processChunk (0eaace3b-4b4c-4c76-93c5-8e8921ae247c:309)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (0eaace3b-4b4c-4c76-93c5-8e8921ae247c:213)``` . I tried pasting your function in instead of mine and now it just returns the value 0.

Comment: Try removing the first or second `return` and condition before it to find out which `split` throws the error :)